# Зачем индексировать внешний / вторичный (foreign key) ключ в MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных

Есть понятие "ограничитель" в **MySQL**. Например, это *первичный ключ* (ключ должен быть уникален, поэтому каждый раз производится поиск "а не было ли этого ключа в предыдущих строках?" для ускорения которого автоматом столбец с первичным ключом индексируется) и *ключ-кандидат* (та же логика, что и с первичным ключом). *То есть, есть логика: будет поиск каждый раз поиск, значит, надо проиндексировать*.

Теперь возьмем вторичный ключ. Он ссылается на таблицу-список. При создании новой строки в таблице надо проверить, а есть ли в таблице-списке этот вторичный ключ. То есть, вторичный ключ ограничивает.

**ВОПРОС: зачем индексировать вторичный ключ?** Это же, например, столбец с номерами преподавателей (а в таблице-списке расшифровывается какой препод какому номеру соответствует). Зачем что-то искать в столбце вида "1,2,5,1,3,10..."?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Основная причина - возможность быстрой проверки на "осиротелые вторичные ключи" (`orphaned rows`) в случае удаления (`DELETE`) или смены (`UPDATE` - лучше так не делать) значений первичного ключа.

Пример:

table `master`:

```
id (PK)   val
1         11
2         22
3         33
```

table `slave`:

```
id (PK)  master_id (FK)  val
1           1            111
2           1            112
3           2            311
```

при удалении:

```
delete from master where id = 3;
```

СУБД должна проверить - можно ли удалить `PK == 3` для этого проверяются все таблицы содержащие вторичные ключи референцирующие столбец `master.id` и только если значение `3` не встречается ни в одном из вторичных ключей, тогда удаление разрешается.

Также существует возможность каскадного удаления ([ON DELETE CASCADE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)) или перезаписи соответствующих значений вторичных ключей значением `NULL` ([ON DELETE SET NULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-table-foreign-keys.html)) - в этих случаях нам тоже нужен быстрый (индексированный) доступ ко вторичным ключам.

Comment: @Dimon, из собственного опыта (хождение по граблям). [Но лучше спросить коллективный разум](https://www.google.com/search?q=database+(why%7Creason%7Ccause%7C~fast)+~index+%22foreign+key%22&pws=0&gl=us&gws_rd=cr)

Comment: Основная причина - возможность быстрой проверки на "осиротелые вторичные ключи"  - откуда эта информация? из какой-то книги / статьи?
по идее, что этот индекс-таблица вторичного ключа нужен для каскадного удаления. То есть, первичный ключ удалили из таблицы-справочника и каскадом автоматически надо удалить все связанные с ним строки со вторичными ключами из связанной таблицы. Но не бегать же поиском по миллиону строк в связанной таблице, лучше по таблице-индексу пробежаться и каскадом удалить «осиротелые строки».